# Laravel passport non-expiring tokens

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, bearer-token, laravel-passport

We're having Laravel with Passport setup for OAuth2, it's working fine in all ways.

Does Laravel supports non-expiring bearer tokens?
If so, what is the way to have non-expiring bearer tokens?

We're using authorisation code grant.

Comment: Tokens are long lived by default, you have to explicitly shorten their lifetime if you choose to. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#configuration

Comment: We don't want to use refresh token, instead token with no-expiry ever

Comment: Why don't you just add years on the boot method of the AuthServiceProvider?
`Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(100));` [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#token-lifetimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Personal Access Token` in `passport`

> **According to [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#personal-access-tokens)**
>
> Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not
> modified when using the tokensExpireIn or refreshTokensExpireIn
> methods.

Comment: but in the documentation it says that "long-lived" means it lasts for a year by default

Comment: @user151496 you can extend it. But every token should expire eventually.